# RadGrid telerik problems with export to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

I added folowing line to my MasterTableView:

```
<CommandItemSettings ShowExportToWordButton="true" ShowExportToExcelButton="true" ShowExportToCsvButton="true" />
```

But when I click on that, loading div appears and then data on the grid is refreshed and nothing else happens. There is no "save file" window.

Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is known issue caused by the AJAX (basically the page needs to return stream rather than XttpReuest used for AJAX) therefore tha AJAX need to be canceled on this post-back.
You can find more info [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/general/export-radgrid-content-to-excel-word-csv-pdf-with-ajax-enabled.aspx) and download few sample projects that show various way of exporting radgrid.

PS. 
The "ready solution" is  to add this to your JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function mngRequestStarted(ajaxManager, eventArgs)
           {
              if(eventArgs.EventTarget == "mngBtnExcel" || eventArgs.EventTarget == "mngBtnWord")
             {
                eventArgs.EnableAjax = false;
             }
           }
            function pnlRequestStarted(ajaxPanel, eventArgs)
           {
              if(eventArgs.EventTarget == "pnlBtnExcel" || eventArgs.EventTarget == "pnlBtnWord")
             {
                eventArgs.EnableAjax = false;
             }
           }
            function gridRequestStart(grid, eventArgs)
           {
              if((eventArgs.EventTarget.indexOf("gridBtnExcel") != -1) || (eventArgs.EventTarget.indexOf("gridBtnWord") != -1))
             {
                eventArgs.EnableAjax = false;
             }
           }
</script>
```

But I still recommend you to read the topic in the attached [link](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/general/export-radgrid-content-to-excel-word-csv-pdf-with-ajax-enabled.aspx)

Answer (score 17):

Add the below code before the Grid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function onRequestStart(sender, args)
        {
            if (args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToExcelButton") >= 0 ||
                    args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToWordButton") >= 0 ||
                    args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToCsvButton") >= 0)
            {
                args.set_enableAjax(false);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <ClientEvents OnRequestStart="onRequestStart" />
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

For the code behind add the below one:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToExcelCommandName ||
            e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToWordCommandName ||
            e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToPdfCommandName ||
            e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToCsvCommandName)
    {
        gridResult.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
        gridResult.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
        if (e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToExcelCommandName)
            gridResult.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
        else if (e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToWordCommandName)
            gridResult.MasterTableView.ExportToWord();
        else if (e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToCsvCommandName)
            gridResult.MasterTableView.ExportToCSV();
        else if (e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToPdfCommandName)
            gridResult.MasterTableView.ExportToPdf();

    }
}
```

reference: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/exporting/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this:

We have a button under the grid:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdExportToExcel" runat="server"
        Text="Export to Excel" OnClick="cmdExportToExcel_OnClick" />
```

And in the OnClick handler you call the ExportToExcel, and then clear the response headers

```
protected void cmdExportToExcel_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     radGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
     Page.Response.ClearHeaders();
     Page.Response.ClearContent();
}
```

On the Grid you have some ExportSettings. 
I set ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true, ExportSettings.FileName to a unique name with current data and IgnorePaging is also true (So i just export all the data).

Works perfectly!

Comment: I'm getting a blank excel spread sheet.  And I'm finding the stored procedure is being called 3 times!

Answer (score 2):

Add a button for exporting to excel;

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="button" Width="150px" Text="Export to Excel" OnClick="Button1_Click"
```

runat="server">

On Code behind Side:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ConfigureExport();
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
    }

public void ConfigureExport()
    {
        RadGrid1.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
        RadGrid1.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
        RadGrid1.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
    }
```

Reference: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/exporting/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: The same result, doesnt work as it should. There is loading div for a moment and refreshed grid. No samve file window

Answer (score 2):

Add the ClientEvents-OnRequestStart="requestStart" to your RadAjaxPanel

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" 
    ClientEvents-OnRequestStart="requestStart">
```

Add the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function requestStart(sender, args)
        {
            if (args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToExcelButton") >= 0)
            {
                args.set_enableAjax(false);
            }
        }
    </script>
```