# RadGrid ExportToPdf() is not working,how to solve it?

Tags: asp.net

> On a button click event I am trying to export radgrid to pdf.

For that I am using `RadGrid.ExportToPdf() function` but getting `"The given path's format is not supported" error`.

find below my code:

```
protected void btnExportToPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MattersGrid.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
        MattersGrid.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
        MattersGrid.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
        MattersGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = "MyDoc";
        MattersGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToPdf();
    }
```

Comment: Try this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012161/telerik-radgrid-export-file-name

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the AJAX because the page needs to return stream rather than XttpReuest used for AJAX.You will find solution for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890916/radgrid-telerik-problems-with-export-to-excel)
Also you need to see on these..

- http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/exporting/defaultcs.aspx
- http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-pdf-export.html
- [Telerik Radgrid export file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012161/telerik-radgrid-export-file-name)

Comment: Hi Ridoy, In my application I am handling two functionality(expportto excel and export to pdf). export to excel is working fine but same code is not working for export to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an UpdatePanel on your page, you may need to register the control you are using to call the export function on the script manager as a PostBack Control.

```
Me.ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(btnExport)
```

You can find more details [here](https://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/export-radgrid-content-to-excel-word-csv-pdf-with-ajax-enabled).